# MCU strange failure

Tags: microcontroller, esd, failure

I am using a STM32F4 chip to build a control device product.

We received a report from our customer that our device does not work properly after having been work half an hour. Even reset does not help.

Then we take the controller back to our lab. We tried to reset the device. It failed to work. Then we thought the MCU could be destroyed and tried to re-burn program into it.

The device then works properly.

What could be the reasons for that phenomenon? Could it be caused by ESD or something?

Comment: Could the radiation caused by ESD or something? It works in normal electronics lab environment. Not in extreme conditions. How could I know if the flashes loses its contents?

Comment: ESD wouldn't produce radiation powerful enough to scramble flash cells. You'd have to run a verification in the upload tool to check if the flash has been scrambled, but lock bits will obviously interfere.

Comment: Does your device use a boot loader? Is brown-out detection present?

Comment: That is a good point! We just sent a product to our customer without locking bit. What kind of radiation would scramble the flash then?

Comment: I have seen some devices (not STM32) scramble their flash memory with bad or intermittent power, such as when changing batteries while the device was active. Don't know if that's possible here?

Comment: No, it does not use a boot loader. We program it and keep it in that way. The only way of update is to reprogram. What is brown-out detection? Clearly I am still at the early stage of using a MCU...

Comment: Radiation doesn't honor lock bits. They only interfere with your ability to verify the integrity of the flash in a post mortem.

Comment: Make sure the power supply is robust enough to reject power spikes and dips coming from the customer's other equipment. What are you using for a power supply? Is power/signal isolation used?

Comment: @rdtsc We made the power supply. The power supply is as following: 220V ac -> (through commercial ac dc converter) 5V DC -> (Through filtering and regulators) 3.3V

Comment: @richieqianle You should mark your question as answered (use the green check mark) under the voting buttons

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you are experiencing flash corruption. That can occur with micros that are capable of writing their own program memory, and that memory is not adequately protected.

The proximate cause might be ESD or EMI or a bad power-on reset/brownout causing the processor to run amuck, but the problem may be that your chip is not configured to protect its memory.

There is generally a power supply voltage range below which the chip is not guaranteed to operate correctly, but you cannot guarantee that it cannot write its own memory (EEPROM or flash). The chip must be forced into reset in that range, if necessary by an external circuit if the internal BOR isn't up to the task.

Usually, by using all the hardware features the microcontroller manufacturer provides (locking and BOR in particular), adding external circuits if necessary  and using a micro that has reset on invalid address and by robust EMI/ESD design (proper ground planes and keeping noise out in the first place) these problems can be minimized. You might still get a few if you have a million units in the field.

Comment: Do you think watchdog could be used? We are not using watchdogs in our product.

Comment: A watchdog could return the micro to functionality after a brief delay if it's gone to la-la land because of EMI, ESD or other SEU, but no matter how short you set the watchdog period I think the micro could trash its memory before the WDT catches it. If your application (without WDT) requires power cycled now and then, that's a hint- a hint that could be hidden until disaster strikes by a working WDT. I prefer to leave the WDT disabled until the system is working 100% reliably.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If a system works reliably 100%, why a wdt needed then? Do you always use a WDT for very embedded system?

Comment: Yes, because even when it appears to be working 100% reliably there can always be a rare event that causes system upset. If the energy of the event that causes the event can be limited that will never happen, but that cannot be guaranteed in reality. For example, a lightning strike could occur very near the device.

Answer (score 4):

We used to have problems of this sort with other microcontrollers. The problem was tracked down to inadequate programming of the devices.

Depending on the memory type used in the microcontroller, it is possible to partially program the chip and have it work normally for some period of time. But some charge leaks off some of the cells because the proper programming procedure wasn't followed.

Again, depending on the flash memory used within the device, some devices use a program, then verify process where the cells are written incrementally. After the cell verifies, a specified number of programming cycles are performed to "over-progrsm" the cell.

This process is repeated until all of the cells are programmed.

The problem we had back then was an improper programming algorithm.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I've encountered a similar problem to the one described (with STM32F1 chips) when the flashing process used incorrect clock.

Comment: Sorry, I could not get what you mean. Why an improper programming algorithm would lead to this failure of MCU? We use the programmer on Keil with JLINK.

Answer (score 2):

Two causes are likely:

1. **Brownout**: Most modern µC have brownout detection, but it may not be enabled as default because it cosumes some power. A brownout is a
   condition where the voltage rails go *below* the safe operating limits.
   The effects would be random, damage to flash memory is possible.
2. The customer connected a debugger to the µC and made a mistake trying to read the program out of flash memory. Some debugging setups erase the flash as first step.

ESD is not a likely cause, there should be some other damage to the chip.
Further analysis would require a readout of the original (not working) flash memory content.